# Cannot get GroundOverlay to show on Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have the following code in `MapsActivity.java`. I'm not getting anything to be displayed for some reason. I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

    private double Lat;
    private double Lng;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    }

    @Override   
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(45.384801, -75.697383);

        GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mackenzie))
                .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);
        mMap.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss `getMapAsync()` call in your `onCreate()` and `onMapReady()` never called. Your full code of `MapsActivity.java` should be like:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(45.384801, -75.697383);

    GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mackenzie))
            .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);

        mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
    }

}
```

and `activity_maps.hml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="<your_package_name>.MapsActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and don't forget about Google Maps API key in Manifest.